# Get Quick Launch by REST call ignoring hidden links

Tags: sharepoint-rest-api, navigation, sharepoint-on-prem, 2019

Sharepoint 2019 on-premise.
I'm trying to get a quick launch menu using this query:

```
/site/_api/web/Navigation/QuickLaunch?$expand=children
```

It returns all menu items from the *Site Settings > Navigation Settings > Structural Navigation: Editing and Sorting*, ignoring the fact, that some links are set to *'Hidden'*. Basically, **isVisible** property is always **true** in response. 
Is it some kind of bug? And how can I filter hidden menu nodes in query?